# Why $location service undefined?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use location service but I get error undefined when I inject the service.

Here is angularjs code:

```
(function () {
      "use strict";

       angular.module("workPlan", ['ui.router',
                                        'geomindCommon',
                                        'templates',
                                        'lookups',
                                        "ngAnimate",
                                        'ngTouch',
                                        'ui.grid',
                                        'ui.grid.expandable',
                                        'ui.grid.selection',
                                        'ui.grid.pinning',
                                        'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
                                        'ui.bootstrap',
                                        'damageEvent'])

           .config([
                    "$location",
                    "$stateProvider",
                    "$urlRouterProvider",
                    function ($location, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

                        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/MainPage");
                        $urlRouterProvider.when('/MainPage/onDevice', '/sites/list');//if request comes from device
                        $urlRouterProvider.when('/MainPage/inspectorArea',    '/inspectorArea');
                     //var absUrl = $location.absUrl();

             }
    ]);
```

**--Updated--**

the error in console I get:

```
angular.js:4587 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dashboard due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module sites due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module workPlan due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $location
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24location
    at http://localhost/Playground/Scripts/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost/Playground/Scripts/angular.js:4458:19
```

Any idea why I get `$location` service undefined?

Comment: `$location` is a service. Only providers (and constants) are available during the `.config` method

Comment: use $locationProvider

Comment: @NexusDuck I updated question

Comment: @Michael what you are trying to achieve there?

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to do? This looks like an XY problem

Answer (score 1):

> Unknown provider: `$location`

You can't inject service directly into config. Use `$locationProvider`

Comment: How can I get path using  $locationProvider?

Comment: Try to use $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) { /* code here */ }); in your config. What do you want to do?

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.rule is used for url modification when url changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can only inject `providers` and `constants` in configuration blocks.

```
angular.module('aop', []).
 config(function(injectables) {
   //the injectables here should be provider or constants. $locationProvider
 }).
 run(function(injectables) { 
   //the injectables here can be instance... ie.. $location service.
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `$location` is a service it will be unavailable in your [config](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#configuration-blocks) block. use [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) instead:

```
.config(['$locationProvider', ..
```

If you do wish to use `$location`, consider moving the relevant code to the [run](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks) block, as it can be used there:

```
.run(['$location', ..
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding $location inside the function

```
(function ($location) {
```

Comment: He already did that, it doesn't work because a service can not be used in the config block. -1