# Ui router $state unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a angular1.5 application with Typescript. I am trying to use ui router state. to load user token before resolving the route.

I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $state

Here is the Route

```
export class Route {

   static $inject = [ '$state', '$stateProvider' ];
   constructor(public $state:ng.ui.IStateService, private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider ) {
      this.init();
   }

   private init(): void {
      this.$stateProvider.state('client', Route.clientId());   
   }

   private static clientId(): ng.ui.IState {
      return {
        name:'client',
        url: '/{clientId:int}', 
        component:'navComponent',
        resolve:{
            authToken:($state)=>{
                console.log('should be done here');
                // console.log('$state before log', $state.params);
                return 'valid token from server';
            }
          }
      }
  }

}



angular.module('app')
.config(($state: ng.ui.IStateService, $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider) => {
    return new Route($state, $stateProvider)
});
```

I have ui-router setup correctly. As the routing works when i dont have the resolve in the state.

Please note that i am using typescript and I have strict Dependency.

Do you have any idea why $state is unknown here?

Comment: You can only inject providers at the config stage, not services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why $location service undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701417/why-location-service-undefined)